# Can I overstay a UK visa? Can I apply for an extension?

Tags: visas, uk, overstaying, terminology, nepali-citizens

My uncle has a visa valid for six month which was issued in April. And he is intending to visit UK in around 1st of October which is apparently 10 days beforehand of expiry date.

the question here is that  he has a return ticket after 15 days i.e. 15th October. What should be done in order to exceed about 5 days of expiry date ? 
is it  allowed to stay after the days of visa expiry?.

Comment: are you an indian citizen?

Comment: It is about a Nepalese Citizen. #ali-awan

Comment: Wow. Or are you seriously asking if it's OK to overstay? Or are you asking how to extend the expiry of an entry clearance?

Comment: I am asking how to extend the stay while you are in UK.
or is it compulsary to return before the deadline.

Comment: Ok, I'll put in answer @AsmitRajbhandari and you can accept or reject it.  I have to go look up the procedure so it will take a bit longer.

Comment: it is very risky do not overstay, also making hasty plan and travel to UK on visit just before expiration also not a good idea

Answer (score 14):

> Or is it not allowed to stay after the days of visa expiry?

It is not allowed. Every UK entry clearance has an expiration date. You need to vacate the UK by midnight of that date. If you remain in the UK beyond the expiry, you become an *overstayer*.

To overstay a UK visa is seen by the authorities as full on abuse and they will get very upset with you if you get caught.  Indeed very upset. They are reflecting the current British public mood which has become soured and angry over media stories highlighting abuse.  So if you get caught inland, it's off to [Yarl's Wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarl%27s_Wood_Immigration_Removal_Centre) courtesy of HM. I used to go there and can attest it is abysmal.

So don't do it. Tell your father to change his flight.

Now to your other question, a bit more interesting...

> What should be done in order to exceed about 5 days of expiry date ?

The law has a little known provision for doing this. It's stated in Paragraph 31A of the Immigration Rules, it's called "[Variation of leave to enter or remain in the United Kingdom](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk)"...

> 31A. Where a person has arrived in the United Kingdom with leave to
>   enter or remain in the United Kingdom which is in force but was given
>   to him before his arrival, he may apply, on arrival at the port of
>   entry in the United Kingdom, for variation of that leave. An
>   Immigration Officer acting on behalf of the Secretary of State may
>   vary the leave at the port of entry but is not obliged to consider an
>   application for variation made at the port of entry.

What this means is that Immigration Officers (IO's) are empowered to do anything they want with respect to entry clearances.  And so a person can explain their situation and request a variation during their landing interview. The outcome of this is solely down to personal impact and articulation skills. If successful (0% chance of this), he will endorse a variation on the entry clearance. If the IO gets upset (and that's *100% guaranteed* unless you are [Dale Carnegie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale_Carnegie) or Kim Kardashian), he can cancel your father's entry clearance and issue him a removal notice.

Nothing prevents a person from trying to benefit from Paragraph 31A (I have seen it work), but things can quickly devolve into an all-or-nothing gamble.

So to answer your question, *yes there is a provision in the rules*.  And 'best practices' advice is don't try it.

Comment: Just to clarifty, is there no way of varying your stay after you've already entered?

Comment: @Berwyn are you serious? LOL. ALL in-country switching routes for visitor entry clearances of six months or less were abolished by Parliamentary Command 5387 and codified in NIA Act 2002 (which received Royal Assent in 2003). It's a hot button and even *attempting* an in-country variation on an SVV will get them UPSET and leave them angry about it for a long long time. Come along lad :)

Comment: I honestly must've forgotten about Parliamentary command 5387 ;)

Comment: @Berwyn drinking all that London Pride has probably addled you. Locate the received gesture for a Stella and put it in an answer :)

Comment: I don't drink stuff like that!

Comment: @GayotFow As a more practical solution, could the Father apply for another visa (normal route etc) to begin as soon as the previous ends (in advance of travel)?

Comment: @CMaster from outside the UK, yes of course. Trying it inland will get them REALLY upset. They can take it personally.  I am trying to say, hey! leave it alone :)

Answer (score 4):

> My uncle has a visa valid for six month which was issued in April. And he is intending to visit UK in around 1st of October which is apparently 10 days beforehand of expiry date.

Read it VERY carefully.

The **visa** is valid for six months from its **start date** or the **stay** is valid for six months from **date of arrival** ? Visitor visas can be issued for start dates up to 90 days in advance of the **issue date**.

If the first one, your uncle has six months from April to **enter** the UK. Then he is allowed to stay for a certain period of time.

I suspect this is the case, because Nepalese nationals require an entry clearance before they depart.

Comment: Who are you and what have you done with the *real* Zach Lipton?

Comment: hiََََََََََََََََََََ

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange. Your username might cause just a bit of confusion though.